# AWS xray put trace segment command return error

Tags: aws-xray

I am trying to send segment doc manually using the CLI with example on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-sendingdata.html#xray-api-segments

I created my own Trace ID and also start and end time.

The command i used are:

```
> DOC='{"trace_id": "'$TRACE_ID'", "id": "6226467e3f841234", "start_time": 1581596193, "end_time": 1581596198, "name": "test.com"}'

>echo $DOC
{"trace_id": "1-5e453c54-3dc3e03a3c86f97231d06c88", "id": "6226467e3f845502", "start_time": 1581596193, "end_time": 1581596198, "name": "test.com"}

> aws xray put-trace-segments --trace-segment-documents $DOC
{
"UnprocessedTraceSegments": [
{
"ErrorCode": "ParseError",
"Message": "Invalid segment. ErrorCode: ParseError"
},
{
"ErrorCode": "MissingId",
"Message": "Invalid segment. ErrorCode: MissingId"
},
{
"ErrorCode": "MissingId",
"Message": "Invalid segment. ErrorCode: MissingId"
},
.................
```

The put-trace-segment keep giving me error. The segment doc comply with the JSON schema too. Am i missing something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I need to enclose the JSON with "..". The command that works for me was: aws xray put-trace-segments --trace-segment-documents "$DOC"

This is probably due an error in the documentation or that the xray team was using another kind of shell.